# Looking for filwever.exe for windows10 - to find out Windows file details on command prompt

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I  have a ton of files of images and want to find out details about them. 
These details show up right clicking properties on Windows Explorer

However there are thousands of such files and so I have to do it in either 
Powershell or Gnubash or DOS

It seems filever.exe used to do it - but it is not available for windows10.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/913111

Can anyone help ?

Thanks !

Comment: Asking for software is EXPLICITLY off-topic.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

Dr. Tobias Weltner wrote a blog post specifically on getting the extended file attributes - it is what you are looking for I believe.

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/01/07/organizing-videos-and-music.aspx

Essentially, the Shell.Application COM object is your friend here:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3'
$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$folder = Split-Path $path
$file = Split-Path $path -Leaf
$shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder)
$shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file)
```

Now it depends on the file type what extended attributes are available.  They are referenced by index numbers.  To get a list of the index numbers and the attribute names:

```
0..287 | Foreach-Object { '{0} = {1}' -f $_, $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_) }
```

If you want to get a list of only the ones that actually have values on your file, this is helpful:

```
0..287 | Where-Object { $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $_) } | 
Foreach-Object { 
'{0} = {1} = {2}' -f $_, 
$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_), 
$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $_) 
}
```

To reference just an individual attribute, just use the index number to the attribute you want to read.  Looking at a jpeg file on my system, index 169 gives me the width:

```
$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 169)
```

Check out Dr. Weltner's blog article for a very useful function called Add-FileDetails that you can pipe output from dir/get-childitem to and get objects out with the details your are interested in.

Comment: Link is dead, use Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20121203050411/http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/01/07/organizing-videos-and-music.aspx